# Managing multiple post request from Microsoft graph api for notification

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am following the example https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications/blob/master/demos/03-track-changes/Controllers/NotificationsController.cs to setup a notification for group changed in azure dev Ops.

The GitHub example above uses Delta Query to get the latest changes.

I have done some modification to the actual project described in the above link, so I have a post endpoint in my code as below,

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post([FromQuery]string validationToken = null)
    {

        // handle validation
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
        {
            return Ok(validationToken);
        }            


        // handle notifications
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notifications>(content);

            foreach (var notification in notifications.Items)
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"Received notification: '{notification.Resource}', {notification.ResourceData?.Id}");
            }
        }

        // use deltaquery to query for all updates and do my stuff(eg:create an entry in database)
        await CheckForUpdates(_deltaLink);

       //when my stuff is completed get the latest deltalink and update the _deltaLink  which is a static object
        var newDeltaLink = await _deltaQueryService.GetLatestDeltaLink();


       _deltaLink = newDeltaLink;

        return Ok();
 }
```

My issue is when there is only a single change this post works fine, but when there are multiple post request within few milliseconds difference before reaching the step

```
var newDeltaLink = await _deltaQueryService.GetLatestDeltaLink();
```

the second request comes in and executes

```
await CheckForUpdates(_deltaLink);
```

twice, so I get duplicate group changes, because the deltaLink does not get updated after the first request.

Is there a way I can manage the post request so that I get the second post request after the delta link is changed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell Microsoft Graph to hold notifications because you are already processing, so any management of this would have to happen in your app. There are probably multiple ways you could successfully do this, but one way that comes to mind is:

- When a notification comes in, add it to a queue that you process in a separate thread/process.
- Process each notification from the queue one at a time, and update the deltaLink after each sync.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I did something similar and the app is working fine.